# Google Sheets how to write multiple things in a cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

Is there and easy ways to make things like this work:

```
=IF(TRUE, " " " ", " ")
```

Or with a method in it:

```
=IF(TRUE, " This is the Name " VLOOKUP(NAME_ID, NAME!$A$4:$B, 2 FALSE), " ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(A1=B1, "This is the Name "&VLOOKUP(NAME_ID, NAME!A4:B, 2, 0), )
```

or:

```
=IF(A1<>B1,, "This is the Name "&VLOOKUP(NAME_ID, NAME!A4:B, 2, 0))
```

or if you want it in two cells:

```
=IF(A1<>B1,, {"This is the Name", VLOOKUP(NAME_ID, NAME!A4:B, 2, 0)})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood what you need, then you can use `&` to join text to the result of a formula. Something like this:

```
=IF(CONDITION, " This is the Name "&VLOOKUP(NAME_ID, NAME!$A$4:$B, 2, FALSE), " ")
```